# The program stack when use torchvision.transforms.Lambda with custom function

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I would like to add some noise to CIFAR10 dataset by using transforms.Lambda function in torchvision.

Here are my code:

```
def my_norm(x):
    return torch.clamp(0.1*torch.randn(x.shape), 0.2, 0.5)

transform2 = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Lambda(my_norm)
])

trainset_noised = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=False, transform=transform2)
testset_noised = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=False, transform=transform2)
trainloader_noised = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset_noised, batch_size=64, shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
testloader_noised = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset_noised, batch_size=64, shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
```

However, when I tried to iterate the  trainloader_noised:

```
dataiter1 = iter(trainloader_noised)
```

The program stuck in jupyer notebook. Can you help? Any suggestions will be thankful~

Comment: I had no problem executing your code in my Jupyter notebook. Have you tried setting `num_workers` to 0?